# GMP mpz_class array not usable?

Tags: c++, gmp

I want to dynamically allocate a `mpz_class` array.

```
mpz_class *arr = new mpz_class[10];
```

This line gives me error:

```
for(mpz_class i=0; i<10; i++) arr[i]=0;
```

It says that i can't have a `mpz_class` inside `arr[]`. Why? What if i want to allocate a really big array? Do I have to use `i.get_ui()`?

Comment: If you want to allocate a really big array, a 64-bit `long` will be large enough.  You'd need over 200,000 TB of RAM before you'd need to use a bignum, and at that point the compiler would probably use a 128-bit long.

Comment: Yes of course, @matt-bryant. I am not saying that I want to allocate that much memory, but that I want to be able to use a `mpz_class` in the "arr[] = 0;". I'm more looking for a reason than a solution.

Comment: You cannot use mpz_class as an array index. Use `std::size_t`. Regarding `get_ui()` it would be useless to use a arbitrary precision integer and then truncate to an `unsigned int` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an arbitrary precision integer as an array index is useless because memory location pointers are limited to the machine's amount of memory and it's CPU's highest integer standard, which today those are 32 or 64 bit.

Classes can not be used as a array index.

If you have to use the value stored in a `mpz_class` as an array index, then just use `mpz_class::get_ui();` to return the value as an `unsigned int`.

**Example:**

```
mpz_class size = 10;
mpz_class *arr = new mpz_class[size.get_ui()];
for(mpz_class i=0; i<size.get_ui(); i++) arr[i.get_ui()] = 0;
delete[size.get_ui()] arr;
```

Comment: 1. Classes can be used as array indexes provided they have the appropriate interface. 2. You gain nothing using an arbitrary precision integer as an array index. 3. syntax for `delete[]` is wrong. Just use `delete[] arr;`

Comment: In vc++ delete[] causes memory leaks. By giving array size it gives no errors when compiling and you won't get memory leaks.

Comment: Being unfamiliar with vc++ I cannot comment authoritatively on its behaviour but I would be very surprised if that were the case. MSDN documents no such syntax extension, in any case the above is [_not_](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=22b3b44d66ff9a1235b147f3438f815c-7063104e283ed82d51a6fde7370c6e59) C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(mpz_class i=0; i<10; i++) arr[i]=0;
  // ^^^^^^^^ int ?
```

Didn't you mean `int` type for the iteration variable `i` ?

Also, why are you doing `arr[i] = 0;` ? This will loose the memory location it was earlier pointing to acquired through `new[]` and causes the memory leak.

Comment: No. I want to be able to iterate to some really big numbers, and "arr[i] = 0;" does not remove the memory location. It will assign the "i" variable in the arr array with zero.

Comment: Did you overload the operator `[]` in `mpz_class` definition ?

Comment: @ChristopherJanzon - you should take the advice given. Getting the `for` loop syntax correct would be the place to start.

Comment: @Mahesh No, I haven't touched any .h files!

Comment: A user defined type is not usually used for loop iteration checking. Its strange to see that in your code.

Comment: That's not a user-defined type, as noted by the `gmp` tag on this question.

Comment: To clarify all this. I use [MPIR](http://mpir.org/). `mpz_class` is declared inside the untouched mpirxx.h. I want to be able to loop with a big iterator. I don't want any 32, 64 or 128 bit standard integers, but infinite range integers!

Comment: @ChristopherJanzon You don't have infinite address space so trying to use `mpz_class` as an array index is meaningless.